# Excel 2010 column renaming based on `if`

Tags: pivot, pivot-table, sql-view

I am importing data from SQL 2008 view into Excel 2010 as a pivot table.

As you can see in the attached image,I have four columns named: `4,9,10,11`. What I need is to rename these columns based on an if condition so that if the column name is `4` for example, it renames it  "requested"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have several options.

1. If the data is imported flat into a worksheet, and you choose to create the PivotTable on top of this worksheet, then you can simply add new columns with the logic you need using standard Excel formulas: `=IF(E2="4","requested",IF(...`. Then, refresh the pivottable and use the new column instead of Movement_Type.
2. Edit the connection properties of your SQL connection, change the Command Type to "SQL" instead of "Table", and use SQL syntax in the Command Text field to implement the logic you need.

   `SELECT *, 
       CASE Movement_Type
           WHEN 4 THEN 'requested'
           WHEN 5 THEN ...
       END AS Movement_Type_Text
   FROM MyView`
3. Change the names directly in the Pivot Table (select the cell with "4" and type "requested". The Pivot Table should remember these names, when rearranging the content.
4. Import the data into PowerPivot and use DAX to implement any logic on textual fields, and change the column names to your preference.

Comment: the source of the pivot table is not an excel sheet..it is a view in the sql.what if i need for example to change the name of "quantity_level_3" to be "quantity" in the pivot table..is there  a way to do that? thank you

Comment: Yes, click the little arrow to the right of "Sum of quantity_Level3" in the Values area (bottom-right most corner of the screen), and click "Value field settings". In the dialog, set the user-defined name to anything you like.

Comment: Also, I have changed the wording of my answer regarding option 1, and added a 4th option.